# onsubmit javascript to reload page but does not dispplay success message in Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I try to reload the page on the current page when submit the form to prevent from multiple data insert in each refresh the page.
 But the below code just reload the current page but does not display the successful message after the form submit successful.
So pleas help me anyone to solve this problem.
My html code for form is as below:-

```
<form action="#" method="post"  onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)">
    <input type="hidden" name="actionform" value="test"/>
     Status:
    <input name="status" type="text" class="form-control" id="">
    <label>Remarks</label>
    <textarea name="remark" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Discard</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-"></i> Submit</button>
    </form>
```

My php code is below:-

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
if($_POST['actionform']=='test')
{
    $data['status'] = $_POST['status'];
    $data['remark'] = $_POST['remark'];

    $insert->info($data); 


?>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <b>Success!</b> 
</div>      
<?php
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: why the setTimeOut? You are using window.reload which will reload your entire page (you will loose all your POST data)

Comment: Thank for your commet progrAmmar.It just for set the time for reload the page. Yeh, I Know the window.reload portion load entire page but I issue was it load entire page but does not show the succes message in it.

Comment: with `window.reload` you just refresh the page. To have `$_POST` data on the server you must send `POST` request to it with appropriate fields.

Comment: Yes, I know the jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Oleg Meleshko. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(function() {

  $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    setTimeOut(
      $("#myForm").submit(), 10);
    return false;
  });

});



<form action="#" method="post" id="myForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]); ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="actionform" value="test" />Status:
  <input name="status" type="text" class="form-control" id="">
  <label>Remarks</label>
  <textarea name="remark" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Discard</button>
  <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-"></i> Submit</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

Try without the timeout.

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() { 
    setTimeOut(function(){
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }, 10);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I try it. But while refresh it show  "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier".  warning but when I click it resend button its resend the data previous data without filling the form.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I had a mistake in my code. The Action should come into form tag and I updated the jquery as well. hope it will work now.

Comment: Thanks for your effort progrAmmar.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use if..endif style, if you want to print HTML in this manner.

Have a look : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php